# Can I call SaveChanges when using raw SQL Query in EF6

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

I want to use sql raw query for better performance.

I was wondering if I could use context the same way as if I committed a query with linq. If I bind collection to dgv.DataSource and made some (update) could I call `db.SaveChanges()` to store the data in the database.

Example:

```
Using context = New BloggingContext()
    Dim blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList()
    datagridview1.dataSource = blogs

    ' if I made some changes in datagridview1 could I
    ' use SaveChanges to commit any changes on button click

    context.SaveChanges()

End Using
```

Comment: give an example of changes the you want to do

Comment: @mohsen.d   I change data from cell DGV . Or in the same time i add new row. All kind of changes i do to DGV. Just like you can do if you are  using Ado.net and bind collection to grid and make some changes and then call ADAPTER.UPDATE(DATASET). See my edit

Comment: Are you sure that using raw SQL query improve performance ? have you made performance test ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/783203/Custom-Object-Queries-RAW-SQL-ADO-NET-Entity-Frame

Comment: @dejan the codeproject article explains how to use custom SQL. In its case, he could have used the `.Include` method to include addresses in the same query or use a projection `.SelectMany(p => p.Addresses).Select(a => new {FirstName = a.Person.FirstName, Stree = a.Street, ...})`. This article doesn't use correctly EF and I don't recommend you to use raw SQL query for such simple query. If you have performance issue with EF, feel free to ask a new question :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**DbSet**.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#M:System.Data.Entity.DbSet.SqlQuery(System.String,System.Object[])) method returns object that are tracked by the context :

> By default, the entities returned are tracked by the context ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.sqlquery(v=vs.113).aspx))

(note that [**Database**.SqlQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database.sqlquery%28v=vs.113%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) results never tracked by the context)

If you change your entities using *Entity Framework* the `SaveChanges` method will persist changes.

```
Using context = New BloggingContext()
    Dim blogs = context.Blogs.SqlQuery("SELECT * FROM dbo.Blogs").ToList()

    blogs.First().Title = "new Title"

    context.SaveChanges() ' new Title will be persisted on database

End Using
```

By the way, depending on the kind of *datagridview* you are using (*webform*, *winform*, *WPF*, etc.), you will have to attach the modified entities to the context that will be used to save changes.